# How to resolve this not found message for FCM in react-native

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase_app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find firebase-common-19.3.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/19.3.0/firebase-common-19.3.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move **maven** to above repositories on `android/build.gradle`

The ***repositories*** should be like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
}
```